# Eclipse java/ant checkstyle issue

Tags: java, ant, checkstyle

While working on a project I need to format my Java code in a specific manner.
If it is not formatted in correct way, the build will create problems:

**Correct way:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  // Code
}
```

**Incorrect way: //Check the braces**

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  //code
}
```

Does any one know for this purpose, which checkstyle should be used/configured in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

> which checkstyle should be used/configured in Eclipse?

The checkstyle rule `LeftCurly` defines the placement of left curly braces:

- `eol`: The brace must always be on the end of the line.
- **`nl`: The brace must always be on a new line.**
- `nlow`: Apply either `eol` or `nl` depending on the length of the line.

See also the `LeftCurly` rule in the [Block Checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html) category and [the Lcurly property](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/property_types.html#lcurly).